# Can we read User object from java.io.DataInput

Tags: java, serialization, java-io

As part of serialization, I need to read/write data (user object) from java.io.DataInput Object.
DatInput supports reading preliminary object (int, long, float, string etc). Can I read user object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to read it with an ObjectInputStream and write it with an ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: am returning back for the same after long while as I got stuck with other work. As you suggest, I have implemented the serialization process as `out.writeLong(this.eventTime); // eventTime - Date in milliseconds ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos); oos.writeObject(this.params); // params - User array object out.write(baos.toByteArray());` How well can I deserialize so as to get the params array back from DataOutput? Please advice.